# Ionic 4 dont execute Http calls when im build the APK

Tags: android, typescript, api, http, ionic4

Im build the APK and testing in the device, but the app never consume the api, the app keep this step and only shows me the alert what im put at the end of the block of the function

```
var headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': '*/*'
        });
    var options = { headers: headers }
    this.http.post('http://ecw.hardcore.com/auth/', {username: form.value.email, pass: form.value.password}, options)
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        if(data.error == false || data.error == true){
            alert(data.name.toString());
        this.router.navigate(['home']);                      
        }
        else{
            alert(data.name.toString());
        }
    });
alert(form.value.email); //Only Shows me this alert in the App
```

But in Web Version Works Fine Fine Fine Fine Fine Fine Fine Fine FINITO

Comment: What sdk version are you running the app on? Sdk version 28+ ?

Comment: Mostafa Harb 24

Comment: Are you using normal angular http or httpClient ?

Comment: Mostafa Harb httpclient

Comment: After success of post Here : .subscribe((data) => {...}, err => {alert(JSON.stringify(err)}); add this to view what is the error exactly from device.

Comment: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},'lazyUpdate'null,"headers':{}},'status':0,'statusText:UnknownError, url:'http://ecw.hardcore.com/auth','ok':false,'name':"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://ecw.hardcore.com/auth : 0 unknown error","error":{'isTrusted':true}}

Comment: isTrusted i think it means the domain should be https, try a weather app api , they are https and make a post request to test if it works or not, socby that you could narrow the errors.

Comment: no the api is http PHP Laravel 5.7 api

Comment: Do you mean its on your local machine? Or online?

Comment: i consume this https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02 the error is the same

Comment: the api run online not local